# How do I find a string in string with regex?

Tags: regex

Despite my many efforts to learn RegEx, I find this quite hard todo, so I'm asking the community for help.

So, I have this string:

```
<html><head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="goforward?U=as4395897a8druasfdas833a">Go</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to find as4395897a8druasfdas833a using a regex. This code is not inside an "" in the real word, although I would like to search for "goforward?U" (that one is always the same).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like HTML. It might be better to use an HTML parser.

Comment: Further to Mark Byers's remark, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
goforward\?U=[a-z0-9]+
```

Comment: You plagiarized me AND vbence. ;-)

Comment: Nah, I just posted later than you. Plus when I tested yours the () were screwing me up. C'mon, don't bust my chops here, my rep is still low ; ]

Comment: Fun to be back in the kindergarten :).

Answer (score 6):

In your example code, this would work:

```
goforward\?U=(\w+)
```

But more information is needed to get it more precise. Since I don't know what "actually" contains or what ends the term you want to find I can't give an exact regular expression so if you comment with more details I can tweak it.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
goforward\?U=([a-z0-9]+)
```

Comment: I'm a dirty thief on intellectual property :)